# Avoid unwanted path in Zip file

Tags: macos, bash, zip, path, shell-script

I'm making a shell script to package some files. I'm zipping a directory like this:

```
zip -r /Users/me/development/something/out.zip /Users/me/development/something/folder/
```

The problem is that the resultant out.zip archive has the entire file path in it. That is, when unzipped, it will have the whole "/Users/me/development/anotherthing/" path in it. Is it possible to avoid these deep paths when putting a directory into an archive?

When I run zip from inside the target directory, I don't have this problem.

```
zip -r out.zip ./folder/
```

In this case, I don't get all the junk. However, the script in question will be called from wherever.

FWIW, I'm using bash on Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Symlink could does the trick. `ln -s /path/to/sth .; zip -rq sth.zip sth; rm sth`

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Your script should use `cd` or `pushd` and `popd` to move into the directory that will be the root of the archive *before* issuing the `zip` command.  How you do this exactly will depend on how the script knows what to zip up.  But, if you want */Users/me/development/something/folder* zipped with internal paths of just *./folder*, you'd need to do this:

```
pushd /Users/me/development/something
zip -r /path/to/out.zip ./folder/
popd
```

That will result in your *out.zip* containing the relative paths you want.

If you need assistance with scripting that, you'll need to show us your script.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the shell command schooling. I like the idea of pushing and popping paths onto the shell "stack".

Comment: no problem.  i do this in one-liners on the commandline all the time, eg: `$ pushd /some/path ; do-something ; popd` ... or even with subshells: `$ ( cd /some/path ; do-something )`

Comment: @~quack: +1 especially for the sub-shell technique in the comment.

Comment: Though using `&&` instead of `;` is a good idea so that the other command does not run if the `cd` failed (typo, or other problem): `(cd /some/path && do-something)`

Comment: @Chris Johnsen: that's a good tip.  i don't use `&&` and `||` as often in my one-liners as i do in scripting, but that's part personal style and part personal failing.  in this case it is the more suitable grammar.

Comment: Is there not a way to do this without specifying the absolute path for the zip file?

Comment: @orange80 - I was reading over this Q&A and wondered the same thing.  I did a little research and found what seems to be a solution, but I am definitely a bash novice, so take it with a grain of salt.  If you want the zip file to be in the directory you are navigating from, you can use dirs and awk to get that directory.  I assign that to a variable and use it in my script: `LASTDIR=\`dirs | awk '{print $2}'\``, then instead of `zip -r /path/to/out.zip ./folder/`, I do `zip -r $LASTDIR/bundle.zip`

Comment: Why are you playing games with the path? Why not use `zip -j`?

Comment: Life-saving answer. I was looking for option to only zip relative paths while running the script from root. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jww i can verify that using the junk-paths argument didn't work for my senario. i needed to cd to the directory.

Comment: assuming, `/path/to` was your previous working directory, you could use `zip -r ~1/out.zip ...` (directory stack shortcuts)

Comment: zip -j works for me and thus, it zips the files inside that folder without including the folder name.

Comment: -j doesn't work right with -r if you want the paths of the files nested inside the specified folder

Answer (score 12):

> The problem is that the resultant out.zip archive has the entire file path in it.
>   ...
>   Is it possible to avoid these deep paths when putting a directory into an archive?

Yes. Use the `-j` option with `zip`. `-j` is "junk the path". According to the [man page on zip](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html):

> Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store
>   directory names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative to
>   the current directory).

Using `-j` means the following command:

```
zip -j myarchive.zip file1.txt dir1/file2.txt dir2/dir3/file3.txt ../file4.txt
```

Will create an archive that looks like:

```
myarchive.zip
    |
    +-- file1.txt
    +-- file2.txt
    +-- file3.txt
    +-- file4.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't this also junk all paths, even those in the 'folder' directory? I think the OP only wants to get rid of the path on the command line.

Comment: This might not be the answer for this question, but it's what I need.

Comment: This answer incorrectly assumes user wants a flat zip. This is a bad assumption and can cause the script to fail if two files in different sub-folders have the same name.

Answer (score 10):

There is `pushd` and `popd` and `$OLDPWD`. Assuming the `$PWD` is `/Users/me/development` do:

```
pushd something/folder
zip -r $OLDPWD/something/out.zip *
popd
```

Now the `$PWD` is back to `/Users/me/development`

Answer (score 2):

### Zip without including paths, but include parent directory, and without having to hardcode its name

A slightly improved version of @quack's accepted answer.

If you are doing this in a script and don't want to have to hardcode the parent directory, you can do this:

```
pushd /Users/me/development/something/folder/;
zip -r ../out.zip ../$(basename $PWD)
popd;
```

The `../$(basename $PWD)` will ensure that the files are retained in the parent directory when extracted.

So now `unzip my.zip` will give a folder containing all your files:

```
folder
├── file1
├── file2
├── dir1
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file4
```

Instead of littering the current directory with the unzipped files:

```
file1
file2
dir1
├── file3
├── file4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most compact version and the one that works best.

```bash
OLDPWD=$PWD env -C /path/to/directory zip -r "$OLDPWD/directory.zip" .
```

This will make a zip file in the current directory named "directory.zip". Inside of the zip file the there will be the contents of `/path/to/directory` in the same exact file structure.

Comment: Does MacOS have the GNU version of `env`? TTBOMK it mostly uses FreeBSD userland. If it does or you do, you don't need a separate variable, just `env _C /newdir zip -r "$PWD/zipfile" .` -- the variable expansion is completed before `env` is started.

Comment: I'm on GNU/Linux so I don't have it. Thanks for the info tho