# Avoid unwanted path in Zip file in makefile

Tags: linux, zip, makefile

I want to create an archive for a given folder but without the folders name in the path...

In fact I want to do the same thing that this post : [Avoid unwanted path in Zip file](https://superuser.com/questions/119649/avoid-unwanted-path-in-zip-file)

**BUT** I'm in a makefile and the following code doesn't work :

```
cd $(PROJECT_FOLDER)
zip -r dist/$(ARCHIVE) $(PROJECT_FOLDER)
```

It is like cd is not done and finaly the archive is well created but with the `$(PROJECT_FOLDER)` folder at the beginning.

Do you know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each command line in a Makefile is launched into a separate shell process.  To get a `cd` to work, do

```
cd $(PROJECT_FOLDER); zip -r dist/$(ARCHIVE) $(PROJECT_FOLDER)
```

i.e., all on one line.

Optionally, for clarity, you could say

```
cd $(PROJECT_FOLDER); \
zip -r dist/$(ARCHIVE) $(PROJECT_FOLDER)
```

i.e., make it one *logical* line, but break the pieces into separate physical lines.