# How to delete unwanted directory paths in zipped file?

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script, zip

Using bash on OS X 10.10 I'm zipping a folder and saving it elsewhere using this:

```
_now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
pushd /Users/me/Documents/local-backups/writing
zip -r /Users/me/Documents/local-backups/writing/writing-bak-$_now.zip /Users/me/Dropbox/writing
popd
```

However my zipped file includes all the annoying directories above "writing" (i.e., from /Users/me/Dropbox/writing).

I saw the question and answer here:

[Avoid unwanted path in Zip file](https://superuser.com/questions/119649/avoid-unwanted-path-in-zip-file)

... but I couldn't see how the solution there could apply to my example where directories are far apart.

Comment: Why change directory, since you are using full paths in the `zip` command? If you change directory to `/Users/me/Dropbox/writing` you can simply zip the relative directory `.`, or use `*` if you don't want the `./` prefix.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  I've specified two directories because the file to be zipped is in one and the destination for the zip file is in another.  What would be your alteration, so that I may understand?

Answer (score 0):

The penny dropped.  It should be:

```
_now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
pushd /Users/me/Dropbox
zip -r /Users/me/Documents/local-backups/writing/writing-bak-$_now.zip ./writing/
popd
```

Comment: Just so! Sorry if I wasn't clear.